# Excel VBA editor auto-UNcapitalizing properties

Tags: excel, editor, vba

Usually the Excel VBA editor auto-capitalizes keywords and property names for you, but now it is un-capitalizing them. Like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Range("A1").Value = "test"
End Sub
```

changes to:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Range("A1").value = "test"
End Sub
```

And then the code doesn't run properly. Any ideas what could cause this behavior? Thanks.

Comment: `the code doesn't run properly.` Could you please elaborate on this?

Answer (score 5):

Possible reasons

1. You have named one of the modules as `value`
2. You have a variable called `value` in one of your procedures/functions
3. You have a procedure/function with that name

**Example for point 1**

[image]

**Example for point 2**

```
Sub Sample()
    Range("A1").value = "Sid"
End Sub

Sub Blah()
    Dim value As Long

    value = 1
End Sub
```

**Example for point 3**

```
Sub Sample()
    Range("A1").value = "Sid"
End Sub

Sub value()
    '
    '
    '
End Sub
```

Comment: Or you *had* a variable called `value` but don't any more, in which case you should declare one called `Value` and then delete it. None of this should cause an error though. ;)

Comment: True it doesn't give an error. OP mentioned `code doesn't run properly` I forgot to ask OP what he meant by that :)