# compile error with vba split function

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to incorporate the excel vba split function in my code. However I get a "compile error, wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment". I have tried the function in many different ways but still get the compile error. Do I need another library? Below is a simple macro that gets the error:

```
Sub testSplit()
    Dim txt As String, i As Integer, FullName As Variant
    txt = "John Q Public"
    FullName = split(txt, " ")
    For i = 0 To UBound(FullName)
        Cells(1, i + 1).Value = FullName(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I tested the code, it is OK for me. Which line give you error?

Comment: the line with the split function in it.

Comment: Wierd, when I put the macro in another excel file it works. Why would that be?

Comment: I don't know, sometime it happen to me. Later, It is OK without doing nothing.

Comment: I see `split` is not capitalized as a keyword which leads me to believe that your project is confused from previous declarations.  Reminds me of @Tim Williams response to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22312696/2521004)

Comment: Replace `split` with `VBA.Split` and see if it works.

Comment: Bond is right, `VBA.Split` should work. It happens if some reference is missing in your project. Go to Tools > References and see if there is a library with word MISSING appended.

Comment: Adding VBA.split worked for me. Must be a reference, but I can't check as it's a work computer and I don't have the rights.